# Windows 10 - How to make the battery charge until a certain specified percentage?

Tags: windows-10, laptop, battery

so I have my laptop plugged in and I want to know if there is a way to make the laptop stop charging once it reaches 100% and start charging again once the battery falls to a certain percentage, say 30%. In other words, I want my laptop to charge to 100%, stop charging, let the battery take over until 30%, start charging back to 100%, let the battery take over.....basically a loop. How can I do this?

Comment: Windows does not natively supports this, but often, manufacturers have a power management utility that you can install that does this for you. See if your laptop manufacturer offers this.

Comment: If your laptop has the app, it does not work as you suggest in my experience. It charges up to the threshold (usually 80% not 30%) and stays there. Both my laptops work as I suggest here.

Comment: It's not good to keep charging the battery to 100%, Or down to 0. Cycling between 20% and 80% is recommended for maximum battery life (for my mobile battery at least).

Answer (score 0):

The settings will vary by laptop model (if the laptop even has the capability).

Here, as an example, are the settings I use and the setup process.  What it clearly shows is the generally accepted 80% charge level.

Set a minimum and maximum range for charging so that the upper range limit is the setting you want for constant charge.

First screen shot is the setting:  Enable battery threshold management; and the two limits - lower and higher.

The setting has information on what you are trying to accomplish.

Second screen shot is the Tray Icon that shows the current percentage. In my computer, there is a picture of an AC plug signifying that the machine is plugged in.

This is what you want to emulate on your laptop.

[image: Threshold settings]

.

[image: Tray icon]

.

Comment: Regrettably, those direction only work for Thinkpad. Battery charge limiting is dependent on *hardware* on the motherboard, and only some manufacturers have implemented that. See https://pc.net/helpcenter/answers/change_laptop_battery_charging_threshold,

Comment: Yes and that is why I said to emulated these steps. I tried to show what can be done with what I have here. I made changes to my answer to make that very clear